# How to Link Tabs on product page in magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

magento 1.9 rwd

I have created few custom tabs on product page. default tabs are description-additional info -reviews. custom tabs->shipping and refund.
 I have given link on shipping tab.when clicked, refund tab should be shown. but i dont know how to achieve it. i cant use #idname as "li" elements dont have id.

Comment: this may help you/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226742/magento-direct-link-to-product-tab have you tried jquery??

Comment: thanks but i have tried it already